# Error "Object required" when running working parameterised Access SQL query (INSERT INTO) from Excel VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access, dao

I'm running some VBA from an Excel file to update an Access database following data manipulation in Excel. It creates and executes the SQL lines via DAO links. On occasion the data to be entered contains characters which ruin SQL (e.g. an apostrophe in the values of an INSERT INTO statement), so an error catching parameterised query statement tries to make these changes.

After clearing the old errors the query statement returns the error "Object required" when it runs, but it DOES work (the database is modified in the correct way). The question is: why does it return this error and am I doing something wrong? Is it likely to be an issue?

Code summary from initial error:

```
Dim TableName As String, FieldString As String
Dim strSQL As String, valstring As String
Dim NewTableRef As Range
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, ws As DAO.Workspace, db As DAO.Database

' Fieldstring is a string containing all field names for the table to be changed'
' TableName is the table to be changed'
' Connecting to database and setting ranges done previously'
' strSQL is initially set by the type of change to make'

' modify the recordset'
On Error Resume Next
db.Execute (strSQL)

If Err <> 0 Then
    ' Only an issue for inputs to Table1'
    If TableName = "Table1" Then
        ' try it with parameters'
        strSQL = "PARAMETERS @var1 TEXT, @var2 TEXT, @var3 TEXT, @var4 TEXT, @var5 TEXT;" _
            & "INSERT INTO " & TableName & " (" & FieldString & ") " & " VALUES (@var1,@var2,@var3,@var4,@var5);"

        Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

        qdf!var1 = NewTableRef.Offset(Row - NewTableRef.Row, 1).Value
        qdf!var2 = NewTableRef.Offset(Row - NewTableRef.Row, 2).Value
        qdf!var3 = NewTableRef.Offset(Row - NewTableRef.Row, 3).Value
        qdf!var4 = NewTableRef.Offset(Row - NewTableRef.Row, 4).Value
        qdf!var5 = NewTableRef.Offset(Row - NewTableRef.Row, 5).Value

        Err.Clear
        Error.Clear

        qdf.Execute

        If Err <> 0 Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB Error Log").Range("Error_Log")
                .Columns(1).Offset(ErrNum).Value = Now()
                .Columns(2).Offset(ErrNum).Value = ii
                .Columns(3).Offset(ErrNum).Value = TableName
                .Columns(4).Offset(ErrNum).Value = PKey
                .Columns(5).Offset(ErrNum).Value = Error(Err)
                .Columns(6).Offset(ErrNum).Value = valstring
                ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                Debug.Print ErrNum
            End With
        End If


    Else

        ' write error has occurred'
        ' log this error'
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB Error Log").Range("Error_Log")
            .Columns(1).Offset(ErrNum).Value = Now()
            .Columns(2).Offset(ErrNum).Value = ii
            .Columns(3).Offset(ErrNum).Value = TableName
            .Columns(4).Offset(ErrNum).Value = PKey
            .Columns(5).Offset(ErrNum).Value = Error(Err)
            .Columns(6).Offset(ErrNum).Value = valstring
            ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
            Debug.Print ErrNum
        End With

        Error.Clear
        Err.Clear

    End If

End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: What is `Error` supposed to be, and how do you get an error when you have an `On Error Resume Next` statement?

Comment: @Rory Ideally there won't be an error the second time - it will just run. I get an error when checking the "if Err <> 0". It should equal 0 because I cleared it before executingthe query.

Comment: That doesn't really answer either question. What is `Error` in your `Error.Clear` line? And how do you get *any* error message when your code is suppressing them?

Comment: @Rory - the error cleared is 3075 - "Syntax error (missing operator in query expression ''Security of members' leadership'." This is the error which leads to the code section posted being called (i.e. the first "if err <> 0 then"). After clearing this error the second (unexpected) error is 424 - "Object required".

I get an error message because I check for errors and write any to an error log. It isn't an error message which pauses code running.

Comment: I guess I'm still not being clear. What do you think `Error` is in the code? It's not a built-in VBA object, so what is it? (note I am not asking you what error you're getting, I'm asking you what you think this line actually does: `Error.Clear`)

Comment: @Rory - Ah I'm sorry, I misunderstood. To the best of my knowledge Error is a function which returns the error description when provided with err (so error(err) is equivalent to err.description). Clearing it is just a bad habit I picked up at one point which (I believe) doesn't have any affect.

Comment: Precisely - it's not an **object**, so you can't use `Error.Clear`. ;)

Comment: @Rory - I never knew! That fixed it and in an area I'd never considered looking... If I could mark that as the answer then I would.

Comment: I'll make it one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Error` is a function that returns an error description from an error number; it is not an Object so you can't use `Error.Clear` - remove that from your code.